# What do you call this sequence?

Tags: grammar

Sorry about the rather uninformative title. I'm curious about what you would call something like this:

> A University of Iowa student has died **nearly three months after a fall in Rome in a suspected robbery attack in Rome**.

The part that I put in bold text is what I'm particularly curious about. As far as my short grammar knowledge goes, I can identify that "A University of Iowa student" is the subject and the rest of the sentence is the predicate (I think), but what would we specifically call the bold text part? Something like an "adjective phrase?"

I'm curious because the sentence makes perfect sense and is complete even with "A University of Iowa student has died" without the rest of the stuff and would like to know if there's a specific term to denote such phrases.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a clause. Clauses have verbs. This is a temporal adverb phrase, containing four prepositional phrases (including two identical ones, which is likely a mistake). I edited the title, btw.

Comment: I'd call it "poorly worded".